# Offset when displaying an UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I display an UITableView, and from time to time, the first row appears at the bottom of the view.

There is nothing above the first row, and the empty space isn't touchable.

So far, I've checked:

- headerView of tableView : is empty
- use plain UITableViewCells
- check the rowHeight of the cells
- check the frame of the cells
- when the bug happens, there is no memory warning before
- check the contentOffset of the table scroll view

This bug appears only on the iPhone, never on the simulator.

The screenshot shows on the left the correct tableview, and on the right the view with the bug. When doing the snapshot, I touched the screen so the scroll bar is visible.

Any idea in what direction I should look?

I just saw the contentSize of the tableView scrollView is wrong: I have 84 cells @ 67 pixels and 1 cell @ 57 pixels height: total should be 5685 but is 6005. (off by 320). Strange.

Stephan

[alt text http://www.quicksnapper.com/files/5161/18374733084A0B3EA24D152.png](http://www.quicksnapper.com/files/5161/18374733084A0B3EA24D152.png)

Comment: You checked everthing I would have checked, and it doesn't appear you're using Sections. I'd check for Sections again and if you're subclassing UITableViewCell I'd check that code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem:

Adding an NSLog(@""). This is weird.

In my viewWillAppear, I have

```
  if (searchByCuisinier || searchByResto) {
    NSLog(@"Will set tableHeaderView");
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
    if (searchByCuisinier) {
      searchBar.placeholder = @"Cuisinier";
    } else {
      searchBar.placeholder = @"Restaurant";
    }
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    if ([filteredList count] == 0)
      [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
  } else {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
    NSLog(@""); // Magic!
  }
```

Adding the NSLog(@"") solves the bug.

Also reversing the test:
Instead of

```
  if (searchByCuisinier || searchByResto) {
....
```

I do:

```
  if (!searchByCuisinier && !searchByResto) {
....
```

I have absolutely no idea why this works (or why it doesnt work without the NSLog).

Answer (score 1):

You can override the touchesBegan method of the UITableView then run a hit test.

Then ask the view returned what class it is.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self]; 

UIView *whatIsThis = [self hitTest:locationInView withEvent:event];

NSLog([[whatIsThis class] description]);


}
```

At least you'll have a starting point. You could also ask who its superView is as well.

Comment: It's an UITableView, and its superview is View.

Comment: Now you know it isn't a cell and it isn't the table header or section header. I'm not sure those are the answers you wanted, but may allow you to track down the bug